# How do I make a command that DMs someone but it can ignore the specific user?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, glitch-framework

So I'm trying to make a command that DMs people, but how do I make it not DM for specific people? I mean, everyone could use the command, but everyone couldn't make the bot to DM the specific user.

I'm using Glitch to code Discord.js

```
if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}annoy`)) {
    const mentionedUser = message.mentions.users.first();
    if(!mentionedUser) return message.channel.send("dude mention someone to continue annoying someone lol");
    mentionedUser.send('Am I a joke to you?');
    message.channel.send("Annoyed " + mentionedUser + "! (Oh wait, I annoyed them 2 times!)");
}
```

No idea how to code the thing :/

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `mentionedUser.id` is equal to the id of the blacklisted (unable to DM) user.

For example:

```
if(mentionedUser.id === "43581349120") return
```

### Warning

This command is easily abusable; I do not recommend having this unless it is for a private server with trusted friends.

Comment: why is it easy to abuse

Comment: People could spam the command, which leads to your bot abusing the API. It is generally good practice to not allow users to cause a DM with your bot if you don’t trust them. You may be able to use this if you implement a cooldown